# How to resolve cdn and add expire headers issues?

Tags: wordpress, pagespeed

I checked my website performance on GT Metrix and the following were the recommendations:

1)  It says as "**There are some static components that are not on CDN**".

2) Add Expires headers"**There are 5 static components without a far-future expiration date**".
Any suggestions to resolve these issues.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The first one says, that you are using components that are not being embeded with a CDN. With a CDN you can have faster data access and automatically have the newest version. But it is not always possible to use a CDN, in a lot of countries because of the GDPR Data Protection.

The second one says you do not set a expiration date for all of your data types. You can look for this code in your **.htaccess** file in your root folder or add it if not existant:

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive on

# document html
  ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 0 seconds"

# Media: image, video, audio
  ExpiresByType audio/ogg "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType video/mp4 "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType video/ogg "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType video/webm "access plus 1 month"

# CSS, JavaScript
  ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>
```

It is possible that you have to define even more, but there is a good chance that this way you will get the improvment done.